# php: best way to validate POST

Tags: php, validation, post

I have been using the code below to validate my user input by $_POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $n=$_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

This code checks whether 'name' was actually set, which is obvious and clear and needed.
Secondly, it checks whether user typed something in textfield to give a value for name.
However, if user gives SPACE " " as input it accepts it because it is not empty it has SPACE.

I found one way of doing it right:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $n = trim($_POST['name']);
    if(empty($n)) {
        $errors[] = "Please give a name";
    }
}

else {
$errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

But here I am repeating same error message twice, so how can it be optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the trimmed string, you can move the trim itself to the if-clause:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && (trim($_POST['name']) != '') ) {
    $n=$_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

If you further need it, you could modify the input before checking:

```
$_POST['name'] = trim( $_POST['name'] );
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $n=$_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I noticed that trim($_POST['name']!='') didn`t work. it accepted space even if i included this in older php which i was using yesterday, now I am running it with latest wamp server it is just working fine.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && trim($_POST['name']) !== "") {
    $n=$_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

Remove the empty, and just do the trim.

To be honest, you don't even need the isset unless you have notices turned on:

```
    if(trim($_POST['name']) !== "") {
```

Comment: I am getting this: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: This does not accept 0 as valid input, but I don`t care if it is 0 or so.It should be at least a single char

Comment: Ah, didn't realise you wanted that too. I've updated the answer in case anyone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if(trim(isset($_POST['name']))) {
    $n = trim($_POST['name']);
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $n = trim($_POST['name']);
     }
        if(empty($n) or !isset($_POST['name'])) {
            $errors[] = "Please give a name";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your above code to this

```
 if(trim(isset($_POST['name'])))
{
$n = trim($_POST['name']);
}
else 
{
$errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && trim($_POST['name']) != false) {
    $n=$_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $errors[] = "Please give a name";
}
```

Comment: Ok in fact before php 5.5 empty only support variable. I have edited my answer. (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: yeah now it is fine. but what is the difference if I use !="" instead of !=false I noticed !="" didn`t work in older php

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to use the following code. It is better because here I can even control minimum number of characters.

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 1) {
        $block->name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }
    else {
        $errors[] = "Please give a name. It should be at least two characters";
    }
```