# Displaying multiple results with 1 button

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

The issue I am having with my code is trying to only display 1 button for multiple results with the same `name` field in my `search_db` table. The `name` field has different ids. I need to gather all the `fullnames` that are the same. It's a very complicated topic to explain and that is the best way I can explain it.

Here is my source code:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="value" placeholder="Hello" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        </form><br />
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $value = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM search_db WHERE fullname = :fullname");
                $stmt -> execute(array(':fullname' => $value));
                $result = $stmt -> fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $db_name = $row['name'];
                    $name = $row['fullname'];
                    $username = $row['username'];
                    $password = $row['password'];
                    $dob = $row['date'];
                    $email = $row['email'];

                    $test =  '<p >'.$name. ' ' . $password . '</p>';
                }
                echo '<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test">'. count($result) .' Results Found</button><br />';
                echo '<div id="test" class="collapse">'. $test . '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concat value of php variable form that you can show all value in single button
check `$test` variable

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $test='';
                $value = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM search_db WHERE fullname = :fullname");
                $stmt -> execute(array(':fullname' => $value));
                $result = $stmt -> fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $db_name = $row['name'];
                    $name = $row['fullname'];
                    $username = $row['username'];
                    $password = $row['password'];
                    $dob = $row['date'];
                    $email = $row['email'];

                    $test .=  '<p >'.$name. ' ' . $password . '</p><br>';
                }
```

Comment: Thank's this worked I'm only new with PHP and being doing it almost 6 months I come across some hard things and I never ask for help but I needed it with this. Anyways much appreciate the feed back.

Comment: Great pleasure here also please feel free to ask anything about php

Comment: Is it best to filter and validate every input value that's being passed to the Database from the user.

Comment: not the best but it's good unless your name contain special characters and go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559623/php-best-way-to-validate-post it will help you more

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful PHP array functions that can help with counting values and removing duplicates.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $value = htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM search_db WHERE fullname = :fullname");
        $stmt -> execute(array(':fullname' => $value));
        $result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

        $namesArr = array(); //create empty array

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $db_name = $row['name'];
            $name = $row['fullname'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];
            $dob = $row['date'];
            $email = $row['email'];

            $test =  '<p >'.$name. ' ' . $password . '</p>';
            array_push($namesArr, $name);   //push each name into new array
        }
        $uniqueNamesArr = array_unique($namesArr);    //http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php
        $nameCounts = array_count_values($namesArr);  //http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php
        foreach( $uniqueNamesArr as $uniqueName ) {
            echo '<div id="' . $uniqueName . '" class="collapse">'. $uniqueName . '</div>';
            echo '<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#' . $uniqueName . '">'. $nameCounts[$uniqueName] .' Results Found</button><br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank's I'll be sure to check those links out!